# How do I transfer my Pokemon Go account to another device (Android to Android)?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I was having trouble playing the game on my android so I downloaded it to my wife's phone (Galaxy S6). I read some posts on how to get it running on my android and it worked but, my level 7 account is on my wife's phone.

How do I get it back to my android? When I sign out and back in it doesn't ask for any sign in info. I've tried deleting the app's data and even uninstalling and re-installing, but it still doesn't ask for sign-in info.

Answer (score 6):

Just use your login info. I'd be very surprised if it stores account data locally rather than on a server considering the nature of this game.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... but when I sigh out and back in it doesn't ask for any sign in info?

Comment: @MichellePurvis Try deleting the app's data to clear login data. Otherwise, reinstall it.

Comment: I've tried deleting the info and even Uninstalling and re-installing but it still does ask for sign-in info.

Comment: Any advice on signing in with trainers club?

Comment: Maybe if I register the level 7 account to the trainers club I could sign in on my android with the level 7 account using trainers club???

Comment: Your Android device is logged into a Google account, it's using that information, so you will not be prompted for login info in the game.

Comment: @pay Yup. Which makes this answer wrong for Android users, so I'm downvoting it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This works for both google account and trainer club account on android, I have done it myself.

Comment: @Theyna Did you never get the “there is no login button” problem, [as described](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273534/how-do-i-transfer-my-account-to-another-device/273537?noredirect=1#comment383729_273537)?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie no, I never saw that; I did the google account move as recently as uesterday. I haven't done the trainer club one in quite a while though.

Comment: @Theyna Since not getting the sign-in button is what the problem is, yes, this answer is wrong. I've edited the question to include the asker's statements about that (which were, before, hidden in comments), so that future readers won't be mislead about what the question's problem is.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thank you, my mistake for not reading all the comments :)

Comment: @Theyna That's just it—you shouldn't have to! Not having things lost in the comments is exactly why vital info is supposed to be edited into posts instead. No fault. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get back in on your other phone at all, go into settings (tap the PokéBall, then settings is in the upper right corner), scroll down to the end, and tap "Sign out". Then signing in on the new phone should pose no problem. It's possible simply signing in on the new phone will log out the other one automatically; I've had no reason to try that.

Comment: When I tried that it just signs back in to the same account it signed out of.

Answer (score 1):

You can logout on Iphone and specify the google account to sign in with.

However, at the moment android devices seem to use the google account the phone is setup with and I can't find anyway around this so you can specify login details. 
You could try setting up a separate user account on the phone Itself. My sony Xperia Z5 allows multiple user accounts you can log in and out with, but I'm not sure how to do this on a Samsung.

You will probarbly not be able to access any of the phones contacts or other settings though if you are signed in with a different user account on the phone itself.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, you need to remove permissions for contacts for it to prompt you for which account to use. You'll also have to link your account to the phone first, as it only lets you pick from accounts already linked; it doesn't let you manually enter your information. At least that's how it works on my LG G5. I think you need Android 6.0 in order to adjust specific permissions for an app, though.

Answer (score -2):

If you go onto her Gmail app and sync your account as well (or however you need to do it with her phone), then go into the game and sign out, when you log in, it should let you choose between the two emails. My phone has two separate emails and it asks which one I'd like to use every time I log in.