# Pokemon go account

Tags: pokemon-go

If I delete and reinstall Pokemon will it still have my progress if I sign back into my google account. Because at the moment I cannot make in app purchases thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I transfer my account to another device?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273534/how-do-i-transfer-my-account-to-another-device)

Comment: Not a duplicate; this seems to be asking about uninstalling and reinstalling on the same device, not switching devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  all game data is stored on an online server. I tried this myself two days ago.

Comment: @user155848 no problem!